# Human race or human breed?

Tags: synonyms

What is the difference in between "race" and "breed"?
Could I say "human breed" instead of "human race"?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to say? _Humans breed other humans, all of whom, whatever their race, would be some breed of human, a strange breed of mammal._ We need more context to be able to help.

Comment: _Breed_ is restricted to domesticated animals (and plants, for those who understand plant breeding). _Race_ is a term for various perceived and/or asserted socioeconomic groups (which may or may not be social groups, and may sometimes include physical identifying characteristics). Like _caste, class, level,_ and many other terms, it's used to classify and sift human society. So the question is which metaphor you imply: humans are animals to be bred, or humans are all the same race (i.e, _race_ = _species_). I like the second one better, personally.

Comment: @JohnLawler The question of whether a *race* is applied to a group of humans e.g. *the Eskimo race*, or whether it is applied to humans in general is interesting. In the days of apartheid South Africa all visitors to the country were given a landing card which asked you to describe your 'race'. Some people used to write *human* in the space provided.

Comment: At least as I have seen it used in older works, breed implies a variety that has arisen through deliberate selection (hence the verb to breed), while a race is a variety that occured naturally.  However, contemporary sociopolitical constraints have seen the last usage replaced by 'variety'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the simplest level, it's **race** for people, and **breed** for animals.

From Oxford Dictionaries - **[race](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/race#race-2)** (emphasis mine): "Each of the major divisions *of humankind*".  [It then goes on to give lots of specific meanings, just in case anyone thinks that's too simplistic a definition of a highly-charged word.]

And from the same dictionary - **[breed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/breed)** (emphasis mine again): "A stock of *animals or plants* within a species having a distinctive appearance and typically having been developed by deliberate selection."

However, the same entry then gives a second definition for **breed**: "A sort or kind of person or thing".  So you could say, for example, that people who spend Saturday night posting to Internet forums are a special breed of people.  That's a metaphorical usage - it doesn't imply that the people share common DNA.

And no, you'd never say **human breed**; the stock expression is **human race**.